# T4MVC Doesn't work property with Url.Action()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

This was my original code:

```
@Url.Action("LoginYoutube", "Account", new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, "http")
```

Which would generate: http://localhost:2543/Account/LoginYoutube

With T4MVC I do:

```
Url.Action(MVC.Account.LoginYoutube().AddRouteValue("returnUrl", Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
```

and that generates: /Account/LoginYoutube

I need the last parameter with "http" in order to get the http://localhost:2543. The problem is with T4MVC I can only put 1 parameter for the call to Url.Action().

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

T4MVC is indeed missing something here, but it should be easy to add. Please try the following. In T4MVC.tt, change:

```
    public static string Action(this UrlHelper urlHelper, ActionResult result) {
        return urlHelper.RouteUrl(result.GetRouteValueDictionary());
    }
```

to

```
    public static string Action(this UrlHelper urlHelper, ActionResult result, string protocol = null, string hostName = null) {
        return urlHelper.RouteUrl(null, result.GetRouteValueDictionary(), protocol, hostName);
    }
```

This should allow you to write:

```
 @Url.Action(MVC.Account.LoginYoutube().AddRouteValue("returnUrl", Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]), "http")
```

Please let me know how that works, so we can decide whether to change this in the official template.

Comment: Yep worked great! It might also be some value to add an overload for doing it the old fashiond way too: Url.Action(MVC.Account.LoginYoutube(), new { Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, "http")

Comment: FYI I pushed a new build last night with this change (2.6.55).

Answer (score 4):

> @David Ebbo: FYI I pushed a new build last night with this change (2.6.55).

That actually breaks MVCContrib grid. Or at least with the code that worked with the previous T4MVC now I got a compilation error:

> CS0854: An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

The code for generating the grid:

```
Html.Grid(Model.Customers)
          .Columns(c =>
            {
                c.For(x => Html.ActionLink(x.Name, MVC.Partner.Edit(x.ID), new { @class = "ILPartnerEdit" }))
                    .Named(LanguageResources.Name);
...
```

But solved by adding this to the .TT (<3 open source):

```
        public static <#=HtmlStringType #> ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, ActionResult result, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            return ActionLink(htmlHelper, linkText, result, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        }
```

Comment: I think that's more related to a different (similar) issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280347/how-can-i-add-a-hash-fragment-to-t4mvc-route-dictionary-actionresult/6302703

Comment: But I'm not sure I understand why that breaks, since I only added optional params. Can you explain? Thanks!

Comment: It's a C#4 "feature". You can't have methods with optional parameters in expressions. http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/18/caveats-of-c-4-0-optional-parameters/ 
I get a compile exception when compiling the aspx view that contains the the grid composed with expressions. (i guess it would be the same for razor).

Comment: Got it! I just pushed that change in T4MVC 2.6.57. Please confirm that the new official template works for you. Thanks!