# Can a T4MVC generated Form include a hash in the action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

I have a simple form where I would like to append a hash variable to the end of the action. My code looks like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(MVC.Checkout.Index(), FormMethod.Post))
{
    //Form stuff here
}
```

Which renders:

```
<form action="/Checkout" method="post">
```

When the form is rendered I would like it to be:

```
<form action="/Checkout#someParam" method="post">
```

Is this possible with T4MVC?

Comment: why not just post the parameters on a normal form post in the form collection?  You would have to modify your routing to do something like what you have posted.

Comment: I want the # so that when the form comes back it will scroll to the correct part of the page (when I can't use javascript for an ajax post)

Comment: How does that normally in MVC when using (non-T4MVC) Html.BeginForm()?

Comment: It turns out you can't do it directly, you have to create the form by hand and set the action to a url.action and then append the hash by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280347/how-can-i-add-a-hash-fragment-to-t4mvc-route-dictionary-actionresult) regarding this problem David Ebbo updated T4MVC to support this.

You can now use the following in an ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Product Details", Html.GetTestActionResult(Model.ProductId), new { @class = "button blue" }, fragment: "#tab-similar-products")
```