# Convert ActionLink to T4MVC ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

Probably it should be very easy but I am not sure that I did it correctly, so I want to ask you how to convert the code below to T4MVC syntax:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new {id = "loginLink"})
```

I tried to do this code and it works fine but I am not sure I did it 100% correct.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", MVC.Account.Login(null, null), htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
```

The Login method signature is:

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC) example:

---

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Dinner", "Delete", "Dinners", new { id = Model.DinnerID }, null)
```

being transformed into this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Dinner", MVC.Dinners.Delete(Model.DinnerID))
```

---

Your implementation of ActionLink using T4MVC *seems* correct.

You include your **link text** - `Log in`

You include your **Controller** - `Account`

You include your **Action Name/Method with parameters**  - `Login(null, null)`

The only thing that I can't find is the correct way to implement `htmlAttributes` but I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280347/how-can-i-add-a-hash-fragment-to-t4mvc-route-dictionary-actionresult/6302703#6302703) example.  You might not even need to put `htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" }`.. instead just try `new { id = "loginLink" }` and take out the `htmlAttributes`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Was this helpful for you?